# Basic Auth working with username:password but not with key:secret Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, rest, api, authentication, woocommerce

I have a problem with Basic Authentication in Wordpress, specifically WooCommerce. I'm using wamp as my local server for developing purposes.. now, in the future, I will use Basic Auth with key:secret (as I find it more secure) for developing my program. However, the GET request on wp-json/wc/v1/customers/ returns 401 Error.
{
  "code": "woocommerce_rest_cannot_view",
  "message": "Sorry, you cannot list resources.",
  "data": {
    "status": 401
  }
}

What I did so far:
Created another admin account, fired up postman and entered account details. Everyting went good as I got 200 HTTP response. Went to WooCommerce -> Settings -> Api/Keys -> Add New. Filled information for the new user, set permission to read/write and generated new customer key and secret. Fired up Postman, user key as username and secret as password, and sent the same GET request as before. GET request returns 401 Error.

I have to mention that currently I have no SSL certificate on my localhost as it is just developing server, and I don't know if that is the cause of my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I feel like every Wordpress problem is unique and hard to replicate. [Here's a link with some solutions on WooCommerce authentication](https://robotninja.com/blog/fix-common-woocommerce-rest-api-issues/), but tbh it usually depends on the specific theme and plugins the site is using.